# Using JoinColumn and ManyToOne relationship but it does't work

Tags: spring-boot

Province:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tbl_province")
public class Province {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "province",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<District> districts;
}
```

District:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tbl_district")
public class District {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id",nullable=false,unique=true) //it doesnt work
    private Province province;
}
```

And in my db:

- **tbl_district:**

| id | name | code | type | province_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NewYork | NY | district | NULL |

//*province_id should be 2*

- **tbl_province:**

| id | name | code | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | America | US | province |

I try save() and saveAndFlush() but province_id in tbl_district always NULL

Can someone please help me. Thank you everyone for take your time!!!